# Facebook comments count returning zero

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-comments

We have been using the following code to render comment counts for articles on a Wordpress site. For some reason, the counts have been returning zero today even though multiple comments exist on the page with the permalink.

```
<fb:comments-count href=".get_permalink()."></fb:comments-count>
```

Has anyone else been experiencing issues with comment counts from Facebook recently?

We tried hardcoding href="http://example.com/" as shown  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) with no luck.

Comment: There is a bug filled at facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/509182015894194 

Seems to be broken since a few hours now ... Hope they get it fixed quick.